# How can I skip the Nth element in a Rust iterator?

Tags: iterator, rust, skip

Iterators have a `skip` method that skips the first `n` elements:

```
let list = vec![1, 2, 3];
let iterator = list.iter();
let skip_iter = iterator.skip(2); //skip the first 2 elements
```

I could not find a method to skip only the `n`-th element in the iterator. Do I need to implement something on my own or is there a method somewhere I haven't found?

Comment: I don't think there exists a specific method to do that, but you could `enumerate().filter(|(i, v)| (i + 1) != n).map(|(i, v)| v)` to skip the `n`th element.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That seems to be a very specific operation. There is no adaptor for that in the standard library or the `itertools` crate.

It's easy to implement nonetheless. One could enumerate each element and filter on the index:

```
iter.enumerate().filter(|&(i, _)| i != n).map(|(_, v)| v)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2cb98ca031dd8e13b7cf84965d558828&version=stable)

Answer (score 17):

I am partial to the `filter_map` version

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let n = 1;
    let x: Vec<_> = v.into_iter()
        .enumerate()
        .filter_map(|(i, e)| if i != n { Some(e) } else { None })
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=469447ea5572ccfa7d7c9677c8cebefd&version=stable)

Comment: What does this buy over `.filter(..)`? It seems longer for no gain.

Comment: The solution that just uses `filter` returns tuples including the index, this returns the underlying elements without the index. It depends on what outcome you want

Comment: The `filter_map` closure can be even more terse as of Rust 1.50, if you like: `|(i, e)| (i != n).then(|| e)`

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to original collection, it could be

```
let items = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let skipped_2nd = items.iter().take(1).chain(items.iter().skip(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

I already wanted to skip some range. The best in my opinion is to create an iterator:

```
mod skip_range {
    use std::ops::Range;
    use std::iter::Skip;

    /// Either the user provided iterator, or a `Skip` one.
    enum Either<I: Iterator> {
        Iter(I),
        Skip(Skip<I>),
    }

    pub struct SkipRange<I: Iterator> {
        it: Option<Either<I>>,
        count: usize,
        range: Range<usize>,
    }

    impl<I: Iterator> SkipRange<I> {
        pub fn new(it: I, range: Range<usize>) -> Self {
            SkipRange { it: Some(Either::Iter(it)), count: 0, range }
        }
    }

    impl<I: Iterator> Iterator for SkipRange<I> {
        type Item = I::Item;

        fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
            // If we are in the part we must skip, change the iterator to `Skip`
            if self.count == self.range.start {
                self.count = self.range.end;
                if let Some(Either::Iter(it)) = self.it.take() {
                    self.it = Some(Either::Skip(it.skip(self.range.end - self.range.start)));
                }
            } else {
                self.count += 1;
            }
            match &mut self.it {
                Some(Either::Iter(it)) => it.next(),
                Some(Either::Skip(it)) => it.next(),
                _ => unreachable!(),
            }
        }
    }
}

use skip_range::SkipRange;

fn main() {
    let v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let it = SkipRange::new(v.into_iter(), 2..4);

    let res: Vec<_> = it.collect();
    assert_eq!(res, vec![0, 1, 4, 5]);
}
```

The principle is to use 2 different iterators: the first one is given by the user, the second one is a `Skip` iterator, created from the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is something in the stdlib, but here's yet another pretty simple way to go about it.

```rust
fn main() {
    let (v, idx) = (vec!["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"], 2_usize);

    let skipped = v[..idx].iter().chain(v[idx + 1..].iter());
    skipped.for_each(|&val| {
        dbg!(val);
    });
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f47a28fd681fee2fe82b57c073d52648

Comment: that only work for vector, `for_each()` is not rusty.

Comment: I don't think that's strictly correct, it should work fine for a variety of types that are `Index<RangeTo<usize>> + Index<RangeFrom<usize>>`, right? For example it seems to work fine if I change `v` to a `[&'static str; 4]` or `&[&'static str; 4]` instead of `Vec`. EDIT: typo

Comment: Also, I've never heard anyone else complain about `for_each`. Is that just your opinion, or has it been formally disparaged elsewhere?

Comment: vector is fundamentally a slice. for your last message, both, it's my opinion, and it accepted use for_each() is not great, cause iterator should not have side effect (or at least avoid it) there is no reason to prefer for_each() when there is the for loop of rust that make it clear is nicely formatted.

Comment: Correct. Additionally, `Vec` is what the OP used in their example, and since the use case in question requires a sequence (should maintain order for a skip to make sense), I don't see why you took issue with me using that in my answer. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each specifically references `chain` as being a case in which `for_each` may have an advantage, so it seems like there may be *some* reason to prefer it. Right? EDIT: typo

Comment: I wonder if this optimization work, you get the point, but still question is about iterator, vector is just here to have a simple iterator example.

Answer (score 0):

More concise:

```rust
let iter = vs
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .filter_map(|(i, el)| (i == n).then(|| el));
```